# Is docker a infrastructure as code technology because it virtualizes an OS to handle multiple workloads on a single OS instance?

Tags: docker, devops, virtualization

I have come across the word IaC many times while learning DevOps and when I googled it to know what it is it showed that it used code as it is the process of managing and provisioning computer data centers through machine-readable definition files, rather than physical hardware configuration or interactive configuration tools. So is docker also a infrastructure as code technology because it virtualizes an OS to handle multiple workloads on a single OS instance? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but Docker provides infrastructure as code because the Docker functionality is set via Dockerfiles and shell scripts. You don't install a list of programs manually when defining an image. You don't configure anything with a GUI in order to create an environment when you pull an image from Docker hub or when you deploy your own image.

And as said in another answer, Docker is not virtualization, as everything is actually running in your Linux kernel, but with limited resources in its own namespace. You can see a container process via htop in the host machine, for instance. There's no hypervisor. There's no overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstud the concept, because neither Docker is an hypervidor nor containers are VMs.

From this page: https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container

> A Docker container image is a lightweight, standalone, executable package of software that includes everything needed to run an application: code, runtime, system tools, system libraries and settings.
> Container images become containers at runtime and in the case of Docker containers - images become containers when they run on Docker Engine.

> Containers are an abstraction at the app layer that packages code and dependencies together. Multiple containers can run on the same machine and share the OS kernel with other containers, each running as isolated processes in user space.

Comment: I'm not talking about container image in docker I'm talking about docker software. The software which runs containers by using images.